# unmet dependencies on old Ubuntu version (10.10)

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dependencies

I'm trying to install git on an old Ubuntu machine (Ubuntu 10.10, Maverick). But i get the following errors:

```
sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libdigest-sha1-perl but it is not going to be installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.13) but 2.17-92+b1 is to be installed
 libc6 : Recommends: libc6-i686
         Breaks: locales (< 2.17) but 2.13+git20100825-1 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.12.1-0ubuntu10.2) but 2.17-92+b1 is to be installed
 libnih1 : Depends: libc6 (< 2.13) but 2.17-92+b1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I do the `-f` part:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.13) but 2.17-92+b1 is installed
 libc6 : Recommends: libc6-i686
         Breaks: locales (< 2.17) but 2.13+git20100825-1 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.12.1-0ubuntu10.2) but 2.17-92+b1 is installed
 libnih1 : Depends: libc6 (< 2.13) but 2.17-92+b1 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

The thing is, I'm not able to update the Ubuntu kernel (due to some ancient software, but where working on that).

So my question is rather simple... How could I fix these dependencies?

Here's the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
```

Here's the output of `apt-get check`:

```
sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.13) but 2.17-92+b1 is installed
 libc6 : Recommends: libc6-i686
         Breaks: locales (< 2.17) but 2.13+git20100825-1 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.12.1-0ubuntu10.2) but 2.17-92+b1 is installed
 libnih1 : Depends: libc6 (< 2.13) but 2.17-92+b1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of locales:
 libc6 (2.17-92+b1) breaks locales (<< 2.17) and is installed.
  Version of locales to be configured is 2.13+git20100825-1.
dpkg: error processing locales (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 locales
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Comment: @neuron Thank you for your reply. I've already tried those commands (found that page to). I've only did not do the dist-upgrade part, because the ancient software. Unfortunately, it does not fix the problem. I've added the `dpkg --configure -a` output to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a newer `libc6` than is available in the Maverick repositories. To revert to the appropriate version for Maverick, you can run

```
sudo apt-get install libc6=2.12.1-0ubuntu10.4 libc-bin=2.12.1-0ubuntu10.4 libc6-dev=2.12.1-0ubuntu10.4 libc-dev-bin=2.12.1-0ubuntu10.4
```

If the newer `libc6` was installed to support some other package, then you'll need to either remove that other package, or upgrade the packages related to `libc6` to the appropriate version (from the logs you give, these are `locales`, `libc6-dev`, `libc-dev-bin`, and `libnih1`).

Comment: If I try to run the commando (without worrying about the other packages), i get the following error: `Version '2.12.1-0ubuntu10.2' for 'libc6' was not found`

Comment: OK, looking at what's actually available, you'd need to run `sudo apt-get install libc6=2.12.1-0ubuntu10.4 libc6-dev=2.12.1-0ubuntu10.4` to get things going (I'll update my answer accordingly).

Comment: Alright, This is better. [Here's the output of the command](http://pastebin.com/eryu2gnw). Sorry if I'm to dumb, do i now how to like downgrade or something the isc-dhcp-client and other packages?

Comment: Yes. I've added the missing `-bin` packages to the command-line in my answer; for the DHCP packages you need to use `apt-cache policy` to determine the appropriate versions and add those to the `apt-get install` command.

Comment: Hmm, `unable to locate package -bin & -dev-bin` But I'll look into that later. And I guess that I've got the only available version for `isc-dhcp-client`, right? [Pastebin with output](http://pastebin.com/b1dY6D7y)

Comment: For the `-bin` packages you need to specify `libc6-bin` and `libc6-dev-bin`. `isc-dhcp-client` wasn't part of Maverick apparently, you need to remove that and `isc-dhcp-common`, and install `dhcp3-client` instead. `sudo apt-get install libc6=2.12.1-0ubuntu10.4 libc6-bin=2.12.1-0ubuntu10.4 libc6-dev=2.12.1-0ubuntu10.4 libc6-dev-bin=2.12.1-0ubuntu10.4 isc-dhcp-client_ isc-dhcp-common_ dhcp3-client` should do the trick.

Comment: [I get this output](http://pastebin.com/neNWJv4V) from running that command. But thank you for your patience and help. I'll dive deeper into these damm dependencies and will have a chat with the devs of that ancient program here...

Comment: Oh dear, I got the `-bin` packages wrong... I've corrected the answer. Try purging the `isc-` packages explicitly (possible using `dpkg --purge` rather than `apt-get`).

Comment: Thank you very much! After doing the command `sudo dpkg --purge isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common` I could execute your command successfully. You sir really saved my week! Thank you so very much!